# Build algorithm without "if"

Tags: c#, algorithm, wsh

There are `List<IClient>` and `List<ClientName>` When the new Client connect to Service(Server), a new client's name will be written to all clients who is in the session.
But new client get only yourself.
I have:

```
foreach (IClientCallBack client in listClientCallBacks)
{
    if (client == listClientCallBacks.Last())
    {
        foreach (var n in listClientsName)
        {
            client.Enter(n);
        }
        return;
    }

    client.Enter(name);
}
```

Please prompt are there variants without `if` in this case? 
Thanks in advance.
PS:Sorry for my English Language level.

Comment: @CodeCaster it has a return when the item matches the last one in sequence

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to remove that *if* you could write two separate loops (that doesn't mean that you have a significant decrease in performance because also your code executes two loops) and yes, if I have guessed your intention correctly, using this logic is more clear.

```
// Get directly the last one and add the clients name already in the 'session'
// to this element. I suppose that the last one need to be informed of the
// clients already in the list.....
IClientCallBack client in listClientCallBacks.Last();
foreach (var n in listClientsName)
    client.Enter(n);

// Now for every client in the session EXCLUDING  the last one 
// inform them of the new client that has joined your 'session'
foreach (IClientCallBack client in listClientCallBacks.Take(listClientCallBacks.Length - 2))
    client.Enter(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` loop can be very useful, but there are cases when the good old `for` loop has its advantage too. Examples are when you are not processing every item of a collection, or if you need the index of the current element.

If I understood your problem correctly, you want a special handling of the last element:

```
// first until second last element
int secondLastIndex = listClientCallBacks.Count - 2;
for (int index = 0; index <= secondLastIndex; index++)
{
    IClientCallBack client = listClientCallBacks[index];
    client.Enter(name);
}

// last element
if (listClientCallBacks.Count > 0)
{
    IClientCallBack lastClient = listClientCallBacks.Last();
    foreach (var n in listClientsName)
    {
        lastClient.Enter(n);
    }
    return;
}
```